# Run arbitrary command on every item in a directory tree in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, directory-tree

On Command Prompt I can enumerate all files in a directory tree and run an arbitrary command on all of them with either:

```
FOR /R %F IN (*) DO @COMMAND-HERE ARGS-HERE
```

Directories only:

```
FOR /R /D %D IN (*) DO @COMMAND-HERE ARGS-HERE
```

What are the equivalent commands on PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over all items in a folder and perform an action against them you can recursively iterate over them and with a pipe you can perform an action against that item

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse | ForEach-Object { # Your command here, $_ represents each file }
```

And I believe you can use this for directories.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {...}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

All items:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object { acommand $_.FullName }
```

Files only:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object { acommand $_.FullName }
```

Directories only:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object { acommand $_.FullName }
```

This will work in Windows PowerShell 3.0+. However, Windows PowerShell 5.1 is over half a decade old. Get current and cross-platform with PowerShell Core from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: @mklement0, I reworded the version information. I understand that there are sometimes reasons not to version up. But, if they can, then they probably should.